# Remove an If Statement after it has been fired once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Is there anyway of removing an `if` statement after it has been fired once?

I have a menu container that shows on page load and want it so when the user scrolls 1px it slides away.  I don't though want a the browser constantly tracking a `scrollTop()` method because of the performance hit from this.

What's the best way to remove or cancel an `if` statement after it has been used once?

The code is below and I have a codepen here: http://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/evbzMQ

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1) {
      $('.menubox').css('left', '-25%');
    }
  });

  $('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
    $('.menubox').css('left', '0%');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

.menubox {
  top: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.mybutton {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menubox">Menu Box</div>
<button class="mybutton">menu</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you actually have two conditions.  One is based on the scroll position, the other is based on some state to be tracked.  So just add a variable to track that state.  Maybe something like:

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( !scrolled && $(document).scrollTop() > 1) { // check the state
        $('.menubox').css('left', '-25%');
        scrolled = true; // update the state
    }
}); 


$('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
    $('.menubox').css('left', '0%');
    scrolled = false; // don't forget to reset the state
});
```

Comment: Hi David - thanks for this.  Now I found the bug on my localhost site this works great.  Can I ask - if I want to temporarily disable the scroll trigger for a set period of milliseconds after the button has been clicked, how would I do that?  I can only seem to find info on setTimeOut.  The reason is when the button is clicked to bring the menu back in, if someone accidentally scrolls as the menu is coming in, it triggers it go back out again mid-way through the animation, and it would be good to remove this for the 1000ms of the animation.

Comment: @EmilyChewy: I imagine you could do some combination of what the two posted answers suggest.  Maybe use a variable to store the state, but also set a timeout whose callback function updates that variable again.  So you'd set `scrolled` to true, then use `setTimeout` to schedule a function which sets `scrolled` to false.  (If I'm understanding the desired behavior correctly.  Adjust values as needed, but I think the general approach would work.)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `off()` within the `if` statement to remove the event handler.

Also note that if you're concerned about performance you can debounce the event handler so that it only executes the logic once scrolling stops for N ms:

```
var scrollTimer;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  clearTimeout(scrollTimer)
  scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1) {
      $('.menubox').css('left', '-25%'); 
      $(window).off('scroll');
    }
  }, 150);
});
```

Comment: Once the `scroll` handler is removed, wouldn't it then need to be re-added in the click handler below it?

Comment: I don't think so as the OP states they only want the 'hide-on-scroll' action to fire once. If you open the menu again manually then you can only close it manually. If that's not the case then your answer solves the problem better

Comment: True, I guess it comes down to what the OP's desired behavior is when re-opening.  Either approach solves the problem, depending on what they want to do.

Comment: Yes I just want it so after scrolling the if statement is completely destroyed, never to be seen again.  This is a simplified version of a JS animation that includes Greensock. Normally after a couple of hours research & then help on the forums I can solve stuff.  I've spent 2 days on this.  I don't know why it's so hard to remove an if statement for good after a user scrolls 1px.  Neither of those (very much appreciated) answers worked. On my localhost site the button isn't bringing the menu back which means there may be another problem. I may have to post all the actual code in a pen.

Comment: I transferred all 500 lines of code to codepen and saw I was missing a pair of inverted commas around a jQuery var which wasn't throwing an error in my console.  

Both of the above worked wonderfully for their respective techniques.

Comment: It's always the niggly things that get you :) Glad you got it working